# How do I use the Particle Disturbance Sensor?

Tags: x-com-terror-from-the-deep

I've built several particle disturbance sensors and given them to my squad at the start of a mission.  The only details I can find about how to use them are along the lines of "Click on the Disturbance Sensor icon on the tactical display. Select 'Use Sensor' from the menu."  I can't see this icon anywhere!  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the sensor like you would a weapon - put it in your hand, then click on it, the same way you would pick between snap, auto, and aimed shots.

Medkits are used the same way.

Comment: They are the equivalent of motion sensors from the first game if you wind up playing that one or know how to use those.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Thanks for the advice about the first game, too!

Answer (score 4):

The other thing of note is how to use the display once you have it. It will show you all movement from anyone within an 8 square radius. It is best to use this before other people have moved. It will only show moving people, so if you have an alien hiding in a closet, it won't do much good.

Personally, I never could find much use for them, but perhaps others have.